# [Help]: d3.js Scatterplot traverse through 3 different arrays

Tags: javascript, d3.js, k-means

Description of what i am doing: I generated a scatterplot. when user clicks on cluster button, old scatter plot erases and the new clustered data shows up.
Initial data to draw scatterplot was array of coordinates. After clustering with dimas-kmeans clustering package,(src: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dimas-kmeans), The clustered data is stored in 3 different arrays.(3 different clusters)

Problem: How i can traverse through this new clustered data (which is 3 different arrays) to plot scatterplot with each cluster representing different color ?

link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/data_x/nk2mhhtc/12/

Important code: (At line 126 in jsfiddle)

```
       .attr("cx", function (d,i) { //d is each array out of 3 arrays
            console.log(d);
            return  x(d[0]);
        })
        .attr("cy", function (d) {               
            return y(d[1]);
        })
        .style("fill", color)//Different color to each different array out of 3. 3 different color patterns to distinguish 3 different clusters.
```

Any kind of hints/help is appreciated,

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

your `clustered_data` in `changeplot` is an Array of Objects while your initial `data` was an Array of coordinates...probably `getClusters` has to do more to pack the right data structure.

Comment: I changed the data format from getclusters() to array of arrays as in data array. for instance, now i have 3 different array clusters rather than single array of data coordinates. i still have problem traversing these different arrays. Please see the updated question & jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/data_x/nk2mhhtc/12/

Answer (score 0):

Donot know why i myself answer all my questions within few days.

Sol: I donot need to change the data format i got from getclusters() rather i need to parse through different clusters and output color in the following way:

```
//Create circles
    var circles1 = svg.selectAll("circle")
                        //.data(cluster_result);
                        .data(clustered_data)
                        .enter()
                        .append('g')
                       .each ( function(d,i) {
                            d3.select(this).selectAll("circle")
                                .data(d.data)
                                .enter()
                                .append("circle")
                                .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d[0])})
                                .attr("cy", function(d){ return y(d[1])})
                                .attr("r", 3)
                                .style("fill", color(d.data));
                        })
```